# Do any jquery sliders slide images as the mouse moves left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, mouse

Like this:  http://www.leica-oskar-barnack-award.com/#/en/information/leica-oskar-barnack-award/

I cannot find a non-flash version of the image slider on this page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did a slider for one of my websites, its here:
http://airio.com.au/

Hopefully it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery plugin Flow Slider](http://www.flowslider.com) does exactly what you need.